# Changing CSS of one element effects other element outside the div

Tags: html, css, web

Whenever i try to move separator up or down, the element h1 above .separator class starts moving along with the separator. Is there any easy way to get rid of this issue?

**Below is my HTML/CSS Code**

```css
.banner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.banner {
  position: relative;
  margin: -0.6%
}
.OverLay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.OverLayContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.overLayDescription {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.OverLayText {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.OverLayText h1 {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 120px;
  /*border-bottom: 2px solid #15a4fa;*/
}
.separator {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #15a4fa;
  height: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 10.4%;
}
.OverLayText a {
  color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #15a4fa;
  padding: 10px;
}
.OverLayText p {
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.OverLayContent {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img src="http://cometoart.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/pojo-placeholder-2.png" />
  <div class="OverLay">
    <div class="OverLayContent">
      <div class="OverLayText">
        <h1>STRICT</h1>
        <dir class="separator"></dir>
        <p>STRICT is a responsive theme with a a clean and minimal look.</p>
        <a href="#">Call to action</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A more easiest will be using *`pseudo`* elements as [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/eLuLo6be)

Comment: `.OverLayText` is growing/shrinking when moving `.separator`. That's why STRICT is moving as well.

Comment: Thanks @SohaibMohammed and Kilian Stinson for your help. Your comments helped me alot in find out my error.

Comment: @AbdulBasit: You are welcome dude! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 .banner img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;

 }
 .banner {
   position: relative;
   margin: -0.6%
 }
 .OverLay {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   top: 0;
 }
 .OverLayContent {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: table;
 }
 .overLayDescription {
   width: 70%;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .OverLayText {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
   vertically-align:middle;
 }
 .OverLayText h1 {
   margin-bottom: 5%;
   color: #FFF;
   font-size: 120px;
   /*border-bottom: 2px solid #15a4fa;*/
 }
 .separator {
   /*margin: 0 auto;*/
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #15a4fa;
   height: 2px;
   /*top: 80%;*/
   position: relative;
   margin: auto;
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
 }
 .OverLayText a {
   color: #FFF;
   border: 1px solid #15a4fa;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 .OverLayText p {
   color: #FFF;
   margin-top: 2%;
   margin-bottom: 3%;
 }
 .OverLayContent {
   position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img src="http://cometoart.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/pojo-placeholder-2.png" />
  <div class="OverLay">
    <div class="OverLayContent">
      <div class="OverLayText">
        <h1>STRICT</h1>
        <dir class="separator"></dir>
        <p>STRICT is a responsive theme with a a clean and minimal look.</p>
        <a href="#">Call to action</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because you are using `.OverLayText` to `vertically-align:middle;`.